# how to collapse a panel by width not display none in ext.js

Tags: extjs

hello I need to collapse left panel by width, means it should not display none, if opened left panel width
is 250 so it's width should become 50px after collapsed , becuase I need to show icons when it collapsed by default it hide completely and it hide all icons, please help how to solve this, please see image for better understanding,

my code of left panel

```
[{
                            region: 'west',
                            title: 'Map Tools',
                            split: true,
                            width: 30,
                            minSize: 175,
                            maxSize: 400,
                            collapsible: true,
                            margins: '0 0 0 0',
                            layout: 'accordion',
                            layoutConfig: {
                                animate: true
                            }][1]
```

Comment: AFAIK you are using classic toolkit. Which version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: @ Arthur Rubens , It's 2.1

Comment: That's got to be like Sencha Touch then, right?  I don't even know where you'd find Ext JS 2.1 anymore...

Comment: @incutonez I don't know more about ext.js, working first time on this, I have seen this version 2.1 written in ext.debug.js, do you have any solution for this issue???

Comment: No, this is not a well-defined problem, so I can't provide any assistance.

Comment: @incutonez it's okay if don't have any solution, But I have defined it properly and easy words , if you have doubt in my question you can ask me.